# cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, serialization, xna

I know where the error is and I have looked over the internet for a solution's however can't seem to fix it.

Here is the constructor in question.

```
public SplashScreen(Image image)
    {  // Create a constructor which requires the image as a variable;
        this.Image = image;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this a parameterless constructor, you need to remove the `Image image` and the `this.Image = image;`.  If you want, you can just add such a constructor and leave this version as it is.

Answer (score 0):

In order to serialize a class using .Net standard serialization API, you need need to have a parametless constructor. So what would I suggest to do:

```
public SplashScreen()
{  
}
public Image Image { get; set; }
```

Comment: I don't know much about .Net serialization, so pardon me if this is a dumb question.  If `set` is private, how will `Image` be deserialized?